# Proving that if an equally smallest order statistic is exponentially distributed then the random variables are exponentially distributed

Tags: probability, distributions, order-statistics

The question I'm stuck on states to prove that if $X_{(1)}$ is exponentially distributed, then so is $X_1$, where $X_1,\dots,X_n$ is a sample of i.i.d. random variables and $X_{(1)}\leq\dots\leq X_{(n)}$ are the sample's order statistics.

From [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/466856/364080), $F_{X_{(1)}}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{n\choose i}F_{X_1}(x)^i[1 - F_{X_1}(x)]^{n - i}$, so should I try show that's equal to $1 - e^{-\lambda x}$ (for $x\geq0$)?

Comment: Hint: it might be easier to solve the problem if you looked at the _complementary_ CDF $P(X_{(1)} > x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $X_1, \ldots, X_n \text{ i.i.d.} \sim F$. Then the survival function of $X_{(1)}$ is $S(x) := P[X_{(1)} > x] = (1 - F(x))^n$.  On the other hand, by assumption, $S(x) = e^{-\lambda x}$. Solving $(1 - F(x))^n = e^{-\lambda x}$ gives $F(x) = 1 - e^{-n^{-1}\lambda x}$, which is the distribution of an exponential random variable with parameter $n^{-1}\lambda$.  This shows that $X_1 \sim \text{Exp}(n^{-1}\lambda)$.

Answer (score 2):

The [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/619645/362671) by
Zhanxiong answered OP's query. This post would address a related result that OP might find relevant.

One can go a step further to show that the relation actually characterizes exponential distribution.

That is, the only non-degenerate distribution such that the minimum of the sample has the same distribution as that of a single observation (with re-scaling) is exponential distribution.

***Theorem:**$~~[\mathrm I]$ The distribution function $\mathrm F(x) = 1- \exp(-\lambda x)$ ($\lambda > 0$) if and only if for every positive integer $n,$ $$nX_{1:n}\overset{\mathrm d}{=} X_{1:1}.\tag 1\label 1$$*

The cdf of $nX_{1:n}$ is $\mathrm F_{nX_{1:n}}(x) = 1 - [1- \mathrm F(x/n)]^n.$

It is to be shown if $\mathrm F_{nX_{1:n}}(x) = \mathrm F(x),$ then $\mathrm F(x) =1- \exp(-\lambda x). $

Now \begin{align}\mathrm F_{nX_{1:n}}(x) &= \mathrm F(x)\\\implies [1- \mathrm F(x/n)]^n &= 1 - \mathrm F(x)\\ \implies [1- \mathrm F(x)]^n &= 1 - \mathrm F(nx) ~~(\textrm{replacing}~x ~\textrm{by}~nx)\\ S^n(x) &= S(nx)\tag 2\label 2;\end{align}

$S(0) = 0$ or $S(0)= 1. $

Observe $S(x) < 1$ for $x<0$ isn't possible as otherwise for a negative $x'$ such that $S(x')<1,~ S^n(x')\to 0$ but $S(nx')\to 1$ (property of $S(\cdot)$). Thus $\forall x< 0, ~ S(x) = 1.$  As the distribution is non-degenerate, there exists $x\geq 0$ such that $S(x)> 0.$ If $x= 0,$ then it is trivial to see $S(0)= 1.$ If $x'' > 0$ such that $S(x'')> 0,$ then as $S$ is a non-increasing function, $S(x) > 0,~~x\in [0, ~x''].$ Due to right continuity, $S(0) = 1.$ There cannot exist $x'''> x''$ such that $S(x''') = 0$ for if it were so, then from $\eqref 2,$ replacing $x$ by $x/n$ would yield $S(x) = S^n(x'''/n)=S(x''') = 0$ but this would imply, as $S$ is non-increasing, for sufficiently large $n,~ S(x) = 0, ~x\in[x'''/n,~ x''], $ a contradiction. This means $X_i$s are non-negative.

Now consider two distinct integers $m$ and $n;$ from $\eqref 2$ with $y = x/m$ \begin{align}S\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) &= S^{1/n}(x)\tag{3.1}\label a\\ S(my) &= S^m(y)\tag{3.2}\label b\end{align} These collectively imply $$S(qx)= S^q(x), ~q\in \mathbb Q_+.\tag 4$$ Specifically $S(q) = S^q(1) = \exp[q\ln S(1)].$ However, $S(1)<1$ (since $S(q)\to 0$ as $q\to \infty$ ); so for some $\lambda > 0,$ $$S(x) =\begin{cases}\exp(-\lambda x), & x > 0\\ 1, & x \leq 0.   \end{cases}\tag 5$$

$\blacksquare$

Note from $\eqref a,~\eqref b,$ that we could have still concluded the same if $\eqref 1$ were true for positive integers $n_1, n_2: \gcd(n_1, n_2) = 1$ (cf. $\rm [II]$).

(The above result was due to Desu; for a generalization of the result, refer to $\rm[II].$)

---

### References:

$\rm [I]$ A Characterization of the Exponential Distribution by Order Statistics, *M. M. Desu,* The Annals of Mathematical Statistics, Vol. $42,$ No. $2,~837-838, ~1971.$

$\rm [II]$ A First Course
in Order Statistics, *Barry C. Arnold, N. Balakrishnan, H. N. Nagaraja,* SIAM, $2008, $ sec. $6.4, $ pp. $146-148.$